# Use SelectMany and GroupBy

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

The following ProjectEnrolment defines a User in a Project and its Enrolment Type in it:

```
public class ProjectEnrolment {
  public Project Project { get; set; }
  public User User { get; set; }
  public EnrolmentType EnrolmentType { get; set; }
}
```

For testing purpose I need to create a list of ProjectEnrolments where:
1. There must be more than one ProjectEnrolment per project;
2. A user cannot appear in a project twice.

I tried the following:

```
List<ProjectEnrolment> projectEnrolments = 
  projects.SelectMany(x => 
  users.SelectMany(y => 
  enrolmentTypes.Select(z => 
    new ProjectEnrolment {
      EnrolmentType = z,
      Project = x,
      User = y
    })))          
  .GroupBy(u => u.Project)          
  .Select(v => v.OrderBy(w => Guid.NewGuid()).FirstOrDefault())
  .ToList();
```

But this gives me one ProjectEnrolment per Project which is not what I need.

Comment: I can't completely understand what you are trying to do. I assume that `projects` is the list of all projects, `users` all users and `enrolmentTypes` all of the types. I know you want a list of `ProjectEnrolment` but with what criteria do you want projects and users associated and how to define its enrolment type?

Comment: @Diego I have 20 projects, 10 users and 4 enrolment types. So I need to pick for each project 2 random users having each a random enrolment type. Just this ... NOTE: I cannot have the same user twice on one project. Does this help?

Answer (score 1):

Although it is possible I wouldn't do what you want in a single instruction using `SelectMany` and other linq methods. It's a quite complex logic and the final instruction wont be readable. How about this:

```
Random r = new Random();
IList<ProjectEnrolment> projectEnrolments = new List<ProjectEnrolment>();
foreach (Project project in projects)
{
    int firstUser = r.Next(users.Count);
    projectEnrolments.Add(new ProjectEnrolment {
        EnrolmentType = enrolmentTypes[r.Next(enrolmentTypes.Count)],
        Project = project,
        User = users[firstUser]
    });
    int secondUser;
    do {
        secondUser = r.Next(users.Count);
    } while (secondUser == firstUser);
    projectEnrolments.Add(new ProjectEnrolment {
        EnrolmentType = enrolmentTypes[r.Next(enrolmentTypes.Count)],
        Project = project,
        User = users[secondUser]
    });
}
```

Version using Linq

```
IList<ProjectEnrolment> projectEnrolments = projects.SelectMany(p => users.OrderBy(u => Guid.NewGuid()).Take(2).Select(u => new ProjectEnrolment {
    EnrolmentType = enrolmentTypes.OrderBy(t => Guid.NewGuid()).FirstOrDefault(),
    Project = p,
    User = u
})).ToList();
```

Comment: This. Your future self will thank you for not writing a 20 line LINQ statement

Comment: Absolutely. Try yo reduce the lines to solve some things automatically generate a lot of potential future headache.

Comment: Unfortunately I am using Linq to Entities with Entity Framework and I cannot do it like that because I will have errors when saving the entities. That is why I am using one Linq statment.

Comment: Thats why I hate of Entity Framework. I updated my answer with a version using Linq

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one too.
Here every user will be enrolled for every project with random enrollment type:

```
 Random rnd = new Random();
 var res = users.SelectMany(u => projects.Select(p => new ProjectEnrolment() {EnrolmentType = enrollmentTypes[rnd.Next(0, 3)], User = u, Project = p}))
.GroupBy(i => i.Project);
```

Comment: I cannot use Random since I am using Entity Framework Linq to Entities. That is why I am using Guid.NewGuid.